# how convert timedelta to time?

Tags: python, time, timedelta

How can I retrieve the clock from a dataframe with timedelta format?

```
#timedelta column 
0 days 01:04:54
```

so that it becomes

```
01:04:54
```

Comment: You add it to a datetime, preferably one at midnight and take the time from it.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't understand what you mean

Comment: What format `01:04:54` should be?

Comment: @AivarPaalberg format is H:M:S

Comment: @NipoRianja - sorry for my badly worded question. Instead of 'format' I wanted to ask what datatype it should be.